# How can I fix PyAudio installation issues on Ubuntu/Debian systems?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio, portaudio

I recently encountered some issues while trying to install PyAudio on my Ubuntu system. I was facing errors related to PortAudio, which caused the installation to fail. After trying several approaches, I found a one-liner command that resolves the issue.

**What is an effective single command to install PyAudio and its dependencies on Ubuntu/Debian systems?**

While attempting to use PyAudio for a Python project, I needed to install it on my Ubuntu system. However, the installation process didn't go as smoothly as expected, as I ran into errors related to missing PortAudio dependencies. I tried searching for solutions, but neither installing the dependencies separately nor updating my system seemed to address the issue.

Initially, I tried the basic pip installation command: pip3 install pyaudio. I expected it to install PyAudio along with any required dependencies, just like most other packages. Unfortunately, it resulted in PortAudio errors that caused the installation to fail. Then, I attempted to install the PortAudio dependencies separately, and I also tried updating my system. Still, I couldn't find a solution that would successfully install PyAudio without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one-liner command, which updates your system, installs the required dependencies, and then installs PyAudio using pip3:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip portaudio19-dev && pip3 install pyaudio
```

This command is has three parts:

1. `sudo apt-get update`: Update package sources list
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip portaudio19-dev`: Install the required dependencies for PyAudio:

   - `python3-dev`
   - `python3-pip`
   - `portaudio19-dev`
3. `pip3 install pyaudio`: Install the PyAudio package using pip3

Now you should be able to use pyaudio.